# How do I sum all the columns in 2D matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I used the following code to sum all the rows in a 2D matrix but I want to sum all the columns instead:

```
row_sum = sum(map(sum,[arr]))
```

Comment: what kind of data type is your `arr` (what does `type(arr)` say)? If it's a numpy array, the thing has a `sum` function that takes an `axes` argument

Comment: `np.sum(arr, axis=n, keepdims=True)`.  Read the docs

Comment: Note that using `np.sum` allows for a more efficient and faster solution than using Python's own `sum` and `map` - since you're using NumPy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
import numpy as np
arr: <2D matrix> 
col_sum = np.sum(arr, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```